# how to add data in a JSON file with angular or javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Hi I've started to make a comments module for my website with Angular, and I am stucking now at one point: updating my JSON file which contains the comments.

Here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "page": "dashboard",
        "text": "first comment",
        "author": "vince"
    },
    {
        "page": "dashboard",
        "text": "second comment",
        "author": "vince"
    },
    {
        "page": "angular_crawling",
        "text": "second comment",
        "author": "vince"
    }
]
```

And the function which add comments to the $scope data, but it's not changing the JSON file

```
$scope.addcommentaire = function () {
    console.log(this.textMessage);
    console.log(this.auteur);
    console.log(document.getElementById('hiddenpage').value);
    var onecomment = {page: document.getElementById('hiddenpage').value, text: this.textMessage, author: this.auteur};
    $scope.commentaires.unshift(onecomment);
};
```

how to add data in a JSON file with angular or javascript ? Is it possible?

Comment: How do you expect to update a file on the server from code that runs only on the client? You need something that runs on the server too.

Comment: node.js is the only solution?

Comment: Of course not. You could do it in PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, Node.js, or any other server-side language, but you need something on the server. You could even host your site out of S3 and update it with S3 calls, but it still has to have something on the server (in that case, S3's API)

Comment: You could use MongoDB's REST API if you want to skip the server part.

Comment: @Goodzilla: Which is still running MongoDB on the server (But doesn't require him to write any server-side code.)

Comment: hmm ok thank you. what is the lightest solution? and it could work only with MongoDB? or MongoDB + Node.js ?

Comment: Nevermind MongoDB's native REST API. It seems to be limited to `GET` requests. You'll find plenty of tutorials (and boilerplates) based on AngularJS + Node.JS + MongoDB, like the MEAN stack. But you should start simple with something like [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)

Comment: Well, I am already using AngularJS, so I don't know...